# How is a main function in a multi file python program called?

Tags: python

I am quite new to Python and I'm working with a large Python code base consisting of hundreds of files. In a particular file, `computation.py`, there is a main function:

```
@click.command()
@click.option("--arg1", required=True)
def main(arg1, arg2, arg3)
  # definition
```

I am trying to trace where `arg1` was passed in, so I need to figure out how `main` is called. Could someone advise?

Comment: `main` isn't a special name in Python. Some code somewhere in your project, likely in the same file, just manually calls it. Look for the call.

Comment: There is no automatic call to any sort of "main" function in Python.  Somewhere, there is an explicit top-level call to that function, that's where its parameters are specified.

Comment: The entry point to a Python script is just the top of the file; from there it is executed statement by statement. `main` is a conventional name for a function that is *intended* to be called as an entry point, either after the file is imported as a module or because the script consists of nothing but variable, class, and function definitions to start and you call the entry point at the *end* of the file. (This sort of organization is typical of code you want to import for testing purposes in addition to executing as a script.)

Comment: @user2357112 Oh I see. I am currently checking for that. I had to edit the OP because it looks like the function is prepended with `Click`. I'm not sure if this changes any of these responses?

Comment: That's important information! It means click is invoking the function based on your program's command-line arguments. You should read the [click docs](https://click.palletsprojects.com/) to learn about how that works.

Comment: Given what @user2357112 said, it is possible that the script is invoked elsewhere or even scheduled in cron or Task Scheduler. One option for debugging is to set a breakpoint and look into the trace, your IDE likely should have an option for that.